# JavaFX GridPane in ScrollPane is bigger than expected

Tags: java, javafx, scrollpane, gridpane

While I was messing around with `javafx`, I've encountered such a thing:
I created a `GridPane`, wrapped it in a `ScrollPane` and filled with `Buttons`, but changed `RowConstraints` and `ColumnConstraints` for `GridPane` beforehand.
The problem is that horizontal scrollbar looks inadequate. I believe that it's a `GridPane` that fat, but how it happens like that?
[image: This is what i'm getting when running the code.]
However vertical scrollbar is perfectly fine.

`sample.fxml`

```
<AnchorPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/9.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="SampleController">
   <children>
      <ScrollPane AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
         <content>
            <GridPane fx:id="gridPane" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
              <columnConstraints>
                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
              </columnConstraints>
            </GridPane>
         </content>
      </ScrollPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

`sampleController.java`

```
public class SampleController {

    @FXML public GridPane gridPane;

    @FXML
    public void initialize(){
        RowConstraints rowConstraints = new RowConstraints(10.0, 40, 40);
        ColumnConstraints columnConstraints = new ColumnConstraints(10.0, 40, 40);
        int i=0,j=0;
        for(i=0; i<50; i++){
            gridPane.getRowConstraints().add(i, rowConstraints);
            for(j=0; j<30; j++) {
                gridPane.getColumnConstraints().add(j, columnConstraints);
                Button btn = new Button(Integer.toString(j+1));
                btn.setPrefSize(40, 40);
                gridPane.add(btn, j, i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`Dashboard.java`

```
public class sample extends Application{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 275);

        stage.setTitle("FXML Welcome");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Get rid of the RowConstraints and ColumnConstraints.  You don’t need them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding the column column constraints for every row which means in the end you'll have `50 * 30 = 1500` constraints instead of `30`. You'll need to add the column constraints in a loop outside of the row loop. Furthermore assuming the constraint lists are empty before you add your constraints, you do not need to specify the index to insert to, since `add` also inserts to the end of the `List`. Please check, if you really need the column constraint created in the fxml, since the code becomes a bit simpler, if you do not need to insert the column constraint as second last element of the list:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    gridPane.getColumnConstraints().add(columnConstraints);
}
for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
    gridPane.getRowConstraints().add(rowConstraints);
    for(int j = 0; j < 30; j++) {
        Button btn = new Button(Integer.toString(j + 1));
        btn.setPrefSize(40, 40);
        gridPane.add(btn, j, i);
    }
}
```

BTW: Note that `AnchorPane` constraints do not have any effect on nodes that are not children of a `AnchorPane`; you can safely remove those constraints from the `GridPane` in the fxml.

Comment: >Please check, if you really need the column constraint created in the fxml.<br>

Indeed, I don't need it. It was created by SceneBuilder and I thought it's nessesary. Really, it's not. I've removed all the `col/rowConstraints` instances both from fxml and controller and now everything works just fine